# How can I turn my old phone into a pure flash drive?

Tags: usb-drive, smartphone

I have an old phone Verizon's Palm Pixi Plus (a very primitive "smart" phone) not under service and  about 6GB, shown by `df -h` and `parted -l`:

```
$ parted -l
...
Model: Palm Pixi (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 6828MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  6828MB  6828MB  fat32

$ df -h
...
/dev/sdb        6.4G  9.7M  6.4G   1% /media/t/PALM PIXI
```

Although its available space is 6GB, when I try to copy a 4GB Windows installation iso file to it, it says the file is too large. I am wondering why.

For that reason, I want to turn it into a pure flash drive, so I plug it into my Ubuntu via usb cable, and the phone automatically turns on and I choose use it as a flash drive, and then as a first step, zero out the phone by

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb
```

But it seems that the phone can automatically recover itself to be a phone from my `dd` command.

Is there a way to turn it into a pure flash drive? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It limits file size to <4GiB due to the filesystem. FAT32 has a max file size of 2^32 bytes - which is 4096MB or 4GiB.

You can try to make a different filesystem on it, e.g. exfat.

Install exfat-utils

```
sudo apt install exfat-utils
```

Make filesystem

```
sudo mkfs.exfat /dev/sdb
```

Depending on the phone, it may reformat this automatically as it probably does not recognize the format. If this is the case... well, you can pick up 16GB USB flash drives from reputable vendors like Sandisk for 2-3$

Comment: Thanks. Is the reason that creating a flash drive of fat32 its good portability? What about exFat file system type?

Comment: It's a relatively simple file system, supported by more or less all operating systems.  exFat is a more modern version of the FAT file systems, and supported by many platforms as well.

Comment: NTFS is what you want for portability. IIRC FAT filesystems can store max 4GB file size.  I've ran into that problem when transferring a large virtual machine via USB drive once.

Comment: exFAT supports 128PiB files. exFAT is not FAT32, it's a more modern, yet simple file system. It's simpler than NTFS, with fewer features, and well supported (better than NTFS in my opinion) on diverse platforms.

Answer (score 1):

The 4GB file is large due to the file system in the phone (The FAT32 is limited to 4GB). For this particular reason you cannot transfer file. It would help, if you split it.

If you want to have it at once, try to format the SD-Card in your phone with EXT filesystem on a linux machine, but I am unsure if this will work.

Answer (score 1):

In fat32 you have limitation of 4GB for any kind of file operation. Try Change file to ext4 or any other which support larger file sizes. Formatting an android storage partition may not be possible, so if you have a sdcard format it to 'ext' partition and you can use that for larger files if not just buy a flash drive they are not so expensive.

ANDROID phones have ability to be a file storage but not exactly like flash drives (plug n play).

Making android phone as pure flash drive may be impossible as the storage chip of android phone is not directly connected to USB and there is no way to access it without custom recovery or OS.